# WiFi: No Hardware Installed and using wifi adapter

Tags: macos, wifi, hardware

I am getting an error 'WiFi: No Hardware Installed' and am trying to use a micro usb wifi piece ([http://www.amazon.com/computers-accessories/dp/B005CLMJLU](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005CLMJLU)). I know this hardware works fine as I've been using it on a Raspberry Pi but it doesn't seem to be recognized on OS X Mountain Lion or Lion. How would I tell the os to use this piece of hardware rather than built-in WiFi?

thx

Comment: Have you installed the appropriate driver? Check this link: http://www.edimax.com/en/support_detail.php?pd_id=347&pl1_id=1&pl2_id=

Comment: thx Melwan- you are correct, I need the drivers and (very wrongly) presumed that they would have existed. Thx for comment. If you want to make as answer, I'll accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To upgrade this to an answer, this Edimax piece needs a driver.

Drivers are available at [Edimax's website](http://www.edimax.com/en/support_detail.php?pd_id=347&pl1_id=1&pl2_id=) for download.